# Can I prevent pantheon-terminal from opening links unless ctrl is pressed?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, pantheon

Currently, a single click on a link will open it in your browser. Sometimes I have many links on the terminal and would prefer to have to press `ctrl`+click to open a link.

Doesn't look like it's possible from looking in `dconf-editor`

Comment: Tumbleweed badge for this one....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot customize this behavior with `dconf-editor`, you cannot change it unless you are familiar with programming (look at `src/TerminalWidget.vala`).

You might want to file a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files